# Making an un deletable and read-only entity with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, entity, jpa-2.0, readonly

I have a table called UserRights containing the list of possible rights that a user can get through a ManyToMany association.
Hence I want this table to be read-only / unmutable. So no deletion and no updates, **even
 through cascading**.

In the hibernate documentation I found read-only entities ([link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch12.html)), however it is not for what I want: quote from the documentation:

> - A read-only entity can be deleted.

Do you know any ways of achieving what I want?
Also, I would prefer a JPA2 solution instead of a Hibernate specific one.

Comment: Usually, the problem is the opposite: you want cascade delete to not have orphans. But if cascade delete isn't turned on, the rights will never be deleted. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @ewernli Yes it is enough and it works. The idea here is just to add protection, just like foreign keys. To make the ORM throw an exception and rollback if by any chance an update or delete is executed on that table.

Comment: @qwertzguy: Just curious why do you want to prevent explicit updates? What if you want to revoke a Right of User?

Comment: @Parvez Maybe I was unclear: there are 3 tables: UserRights, User and User_UserRights. The later is an association table using ManyToMany annotation. So I can revoke a right by deleting the corresponding user_id and userRights_id record from the User_UserRights table. However I want the UserRights table to be read-only. It contains the list of all possible rights a user can have.

Comment: This is hibernate specific but have you tried @org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(mutable = false) ?